# Is it possible to digitally stop a moving motorbike using an Arduino module?

Tags: arduino-uno, android, project

I am working on a bike protection project that is supposed to be part of my CS syllabus. Although I got most of the things worked out, there is one thing that bugs me; that is to how to stop a moving bike using an Arduino built into the bike, possibly from a remote system, like another Arduino or Android app.

Is it possible to do it using an Arduino and some other modules maybe?

Comment: Put a (NC-)relay in series with the ignition cable. That way you can "remove the key" using the Arduino.

Comment: with autos in general, it might be illegal to stop it if its moving, as that could cause a wreck and expose you to injury liability. its best to keep it from being started, or kill it when idle.

Comment: Legality might not be an issue here as this is just a throwaway project I have to do for internals.I am not really aiming to make this a commercial product.

Comment: Make an actuator poke a stick through the wheel, this often is very (or too) effective. (:

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you simply want to stop the engine, Gerben's comment has the answer: Put a relay in series with the ignition. Control the relay with the Arduino.

Opening the relay breaks the circuit. Ignition is now off, and the engine will no longer run.

Of course, the bike can still roll without engine power. If you want to completely immobilize the bike, you need to engage the brakes, or lock the wheels in some other way. And that takes a whole lot more hardware.

Comment: starting an engine can draw 50 amps, make sure the relay can handle that much current (most cannot)

Comment: If the motorbike has a starter motor, I hope it's on a relay of its own.

Comment: If you try to use the brakes with the Arduino, make sure you do it gently; an abrupt break (especially on the front wheel) might cause lethal injuries.